# how to publish laser data after manipulation?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

am using a sick laser to get some data, i then remove some of the data but do it as a std::vector. but i'm unable to publish those points to ros.
is there a vector to sensor_msgs conversion that needs to be done?

thanks for any help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28622/how-to-publish-laser-data-after-manipulation?/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-27**:
Could you post a simple chunk of code showing what you are attempting to do? (e.g. your subscribe, modify, publish portion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can directly assign a `std::vector<float>` to the `float32[] ranges` field of the `LaserScan` message:

```
sensor_msgs::LaserScan filtered_scan_msg;
std::vector<float> filtered_ranges;
// fill out vector here...
filtered_scan_msg.ranges = filtered_ranges;
```

Keep in mind that there are a lot of other fileds of the `LaserScan` message that need to be correclty set - `angle_min`, `angle_max`, `angle_increment`, etc.

For a working C++ example, you can look at `laser_scan_splitter.cpp` in [laser_scan_splitter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_splitter).

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3